# Pixelated Text in swift UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently struggling with two labels I have in a UIWindow that "floats" over my view controllers. The text on the labels appears pixelated or blurry. I've read in other threads that this can be caused by the frame using floating numbers, but I've tried using the round() function inside the CGRectMake as well as CGRectIntegral() on the labels' frames and it makes no difference. I've also tried a variety of fonts and sizes and they all come back blurry. Is there something I might be missing? Code below:

```
    miniPlayer.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, atIndex: 0)

    avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, round(miniPlayer.bounds.width / 3), round(miniPlayer.bounds.height))
    avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectIntegral(avPlayerLayer.frame) 
    miniPlayer.addSubview(minLabel)
    minLabel.frame = CGRectMake(avPlayerLayer.bounds.width + 45, 10, 150, 30)
    minLabel.frame = CGRectIntegral(minLabel.frame)
    minLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    minLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 17)
    minLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    minLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    minLabel.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I say it's something related to the label properties not the frame. Have you tried deleting `lineBreakMode` & `contentScaleFactor`? I encountered a similar issue before and the problem was that a property was set to `scaleToFit`. So my guess is that something is stretching your label, even though it doesn't change it's size.

Comment: Yes I tried deleting those... I actually just resolved it by changing
   " minLabel.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale"
To
    "minLabel.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale * 3"
But I have no idea why that works.